# pin_ptr of List rather than array

Tags: c++-cli

I use pin_ptr for cli::array types and everything works fine.

Is it possible to do the same with System::Collection::Generic::List which I believe is a contiguous block of memory?

The obvious

```
List<double>^ stuff = gcnew List<double>( 10 );

cli::pin_ptr<double> resultPtr = &stuff[ 0 ];
```

gives a compiler error "error C2102: '&' requires l-value" presumably because the indexed property returns something that is not a l-value! So is there another way to do this. I have played around with interior_ptr as well but have not found anything that works yet.

I know that I could call ToArray on the List but the whole point is to not copy stuff around.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.

True, a List does use an array behind the scenes, but the `[]` operator is different. With an array, `[]` is simple pointer math, but with a List, `[]` is a full-fledged method call. That's why the `&` isn't working: you can take the address of an array location, but you can't take the address of a value returned from a method.

Think about it like this: If they wanted to, they could change the implementation of `List` without changing its external interface. It would be possible to change List to store the list contents in memory gzip-compressed. In that case, `stuff[0]` is generated on-the-fly by the `[]` method which does the decompression, so there is no single memory location that contains `stuff[0]` to pin.

### Edit

Yes, *internal to the List class*, the contents are contiguous in memory. You can see this in the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs) that Microsoft has provided. However, the List class does not make that array public: The public interface to the List class is the public methods & properties, only. The public methods & properties present a contract, and the array that the values are stored in are not part of that contract. Microsoft would never do this, but they could do a gzip-compressed implementation of List, and the public contract of the List class wouldn't change. You should only write your code to the public methods & properties of a class, not to the internals that may change at any time.

Comment: Intersting, your reply seems to indicate that List may not be contigous in memory. However https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379570(v=vs.80).aspx seems to strongly imply that it is. Do you know if there is a definitive answer from Microsoft? Definitive as in "yes it is contiguous" or "it may be at the moment but we reserve the right to change that in future"

Comment: Yes, it is contiguous, and Microsoft isn't going to change it, but it wouldn't be considered a breaking change if they did. See edit.

Comment: Notably, part of what is documented is O(1) access, so it's sort-of implied that it's a contiguous block (hence they would never gzip the internals). At the end of the day, us CLR programmers rely on the "wisdom" of the JIT to optimize these low-level details, and the end assembly code mostly does as much as we would were we to use pointers for optimizations.